# What is Castle Windsor's DependsOn Equivalent in Unity?

Tags: dependency-injection, castle-windsor, unity-container

I use DependsOn for static dependencies such as connection strings. What is the equivalent function for Unity's Fluent interface?

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the value directly in the RegisterType call as the value for a parameter or property.

For example, if you have this class:

```
public class Clock {
    public Clock(int startTicks) { ... }
    public Clock(DateTime startTime) { ... }
}
```

You could configure this like so:

```
container.RegisterType<Clock>(
    new InjectionConstructor(154324));
```

and it'll pass that integer to the constructor that takes a single int. If you'd passed a DateTime instead, it'd call the other constructor.